# Prove that for all integers $a$ and $b$ there is an integer $c$ such that $a | c$ and $b | c$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

This is Velleman's exercise 3.4.25:

Prove that for all integers a and b there is an integer c such that a | c and b | c.

A proof in Velleman's expository style would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edits:

I know that c = ab is the requirement! The first chapter of the book is about sentential logic, the second one is about quantificational logic and in the third one he progresses to proofs!

Doesn't the proof statement mean ∀a∀b∃c(a|c ∧ b|c)? How from there we could justifiably deduce c = ab?

For you to get familiar with his expository style I'll copy and paste one example from the book in here to see what I mean:

Prove for every integer n, 6 | n iff 2 | n and 3 | n.

Proof. Let n be an arbitrary integer.

(→) Suppose 6 | n. Then we can choose an integer k such that 6k = n.
Therefore n = 6k = 2(3k), so 2 | n, and similarly n = 6k = 3(2k), so 3 | n.

(←) Suppose 2 | n and 3 | n. Then we can choose integers j and k such
that n = 2 j and n = 3k. Therefore 6( j − k) = 6 j − 6k = 3(2 j) − 2(3k) =
3n − 2n = n, so 6 | n.

Comment: what products divide both a and b.

Comment: Please provide further context: what number theory did you learn before this, and what is "Velleman's expository style"?

Comment: You don't "deduce that $c=ab$." You reason that $c=ab$ is one example, but there could be many such $c$ - indeed there are. That's different from the example of $2,3\mid n\iff 6\mid n$ because now you are trying to classify *all* such $n$ with $2,3\mid n$.

Comment: Yeah... that's right! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know his style, but $c=ab$ satisfies the requirement.

Comment: Presumably the OP wants some *motivation* or *intuition* for discovering the answer, not simply pulling it out of a hat like above (which *spoils* any potential learning experience).

Comment: @BillDubuque How do you motivate that answer?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That will depend on the OP further clarifying their  context  (namely "Velleman's style" and what  they learned before this). It's truly unfortunate that FGITW answerers always spoil questions like this. But such are the defects of gamified platforms.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\, a\mid c\iff c = na,\,$ so we need to find $n$ such that $\,b\mid c = na.\,$ It suffices that $\,b\mid n\ $ (why?)

Comment: Note: this answer (and the 2 others) were posted before the OP added context (everything after "Edits:...").

Answer (score 0):

Expository, hm.

What integers does an integer $a$ divide? Clearly any such number is a multiple of $a$, so we have $a \mid ka, k\in \Bbb Z$ and when we undertake the division $\dfrac{ka}{a}$ we retrieve $k$ as the result and thus every integer that $a$ divides is of this form.

Similarly every integer that $b$ divides is of the form $jb, j\in \Bbb Z$.

So we need to find whether these two characterizations can coincide: can we have $c=ak$ and also $c=jb$? Since both $k$ and $j$ can be any integer, there is an easy choice available; we can set $k=b$ and $j=a$ to find that $c=ab$ is divisible by both $a$ and $b$.